# How to filter invalid parameters in the curl command data using Jersey framework

Tags: jersey

**My resource class:**

```
    @POST 
    @Path("/add")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Object add(Flow flow){
        Object obj = fun(flow.getParam1(),flow.getParam2());
        return obj;
    }
```

Flow is a `JAXB` class, all `params` are its member variables.
**Commands used:**

```
curl -X POST -HContent-type:application/xml -k --data "<rootElementName param1=\"val1\" param2=\"val2\"/>" https://<ip>:8443/xxxx/add

curl -X POST -HContent-type:application/json -k --data "{\"@param1\":\"val1\",\"@param2\":\"val2\"}" https://<ip>:8443/xxxx/add
```

My requirement is to identify invalid parameter name and through error. 
**Ex:**

```
curl -X POST -HContent-type:application/xml -k --data "<rootElementName invalidParam1=\"val1\" param2=\"val2\"/>" https://<ip>:8443/xxxx/add
```

Resource class has to validate this data and return message Invalid `param`: invalidParam1
For HTTP GET method, I have done this by iterating the multi valued map `uriInfo.getQueryParameters()`

Please suggest better way to do this invalid `param` validation for `POST` method (if possible by reusing the multi valued map validation code)